# Если передавать вектор по значению - возвращает цифры, а по указателю возвращает правильный ответ. Объясните почему?

Tags: c++

По значению дает набор цифр :

```
int recursiveMinimum(vector<int>array)
{
static int min = INT_MAX, count = 0;
if (count < array.size())
{
    if (array[count] <= min)
        min = array[count];
    count++;
    recursiveMinimum(array);
}
else
    return min;
}
```

По указателю дает правильный ответ:

```
int recursiveMinimum(vector<int>&array)
{
    static int min = INT_MAX, count = 0;
    if (count < array.size())
    {
        if (array[count] <= min)
            min = array[count];
        count++;
        recursiveMinimum(array);
    }
    else
        return min;
}
```

Comment: Скажите, при компилировании данного кода, компилятор, которым вы пользуетесь, не выдаёт предупреждения типа `control reaches end of non-void function`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас отсутствует `return` в первой ветке `if`. Ваша функция ничего не возвращает ни из одного уровня рекурсии, кроме самого нижнего. Поведение не определено в обоих вариантах, т.е. ваше возвращенное на самый верх значение - это просто мусор.

А то, что этот мусор случайно совпадает с правильным ответом во втором варианте - известный феномен, заключающийся в том, что при отсутствующем `return` иногда получается так, что из наивно странслированного кода (без оптимизаций и т.п.) "как бы возвращается" последнее вычисленное значение (например, регистр `eax` для значения типа `int` на платформе x86), если оно не будет затерто другим кодом при выходе из функции.

При передаче по значению при выходе из функции будет вызываться деструктор `array`, который с большой долей вероятности затрет содержимое `eax`, в результате чего из функции будет "возвращен" совсем посторонний мусор. При передаче по ссылке при выходе из функции ничего не делается и последнее значение `eax` сохраняется в нетронутом виде. Из-за этого создается иллюзия того, что второй вариант "работает правильно".

Разумеется, любой чих в организации кода или в настройках компилятора будет убивать эту случайную "работоспособность" вашего второго варианта.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение .

Comment: @shak: Я не знаю, как и куда вы там поставили этот `return`.